# ¿Como cargar un array multidimensional con datos dinamicos?

Tags: php, array

no se nada de como hacer esto, pero me explicaré...

Tengo una base de datos, en la cual obtengo una cantidad X de ruts.
Esta cantidad X las asigno dentro de un array de este modo:

```
$arraySucursales = [];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE status = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rut = $fila["rut"];
        array_push($arraySucursales, $rut);
    }
}
```

Ahora, tengo esos ruts cargados dentro, pero ahora, quiero agregarle subdatos.
Los ruts tienen una sucursal, por lo que quiero añadir esas sucursales dentro del array, pero que estas solo queden ligadas a 1 rut. Algo como esto, pero dentro del array:

```
- Rut: 123 - Sucursales: 1, 2, 3
- Rut: 124 - Sucursales: 1
- Rut: 125 - Sucursales: 1, 2
```

No se si me estoy explicando bien, pero no logro obtener eso, solo he podido hacer esto:

```
$arraySucursales = [];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE status = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //echo $fila["rut"] . "</br>";
        $rut = $fila["rut"];
        array_push($arraySucursales, $rut);
        $drut = $raiz . "/" . $rut;
        $dirRut = opendir($drut);
        while ($sucursales = readdir($dirRut)) {
            if ($sucursales != "." && $sucursales != "..") {
                //echo $sucursales . "</br>";
                array_push($arraySucursales, [$rut, $sucursal]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array(9) { [0]=> string(10) "15835677-5" [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } [4]=> string(10) "77187151-8" [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } [6]=> string(9) "8935288-6" [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa las *rut* como índices del arreglo:

```
$arraySucursales = [];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE status = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rut = $fila["rut"];
        // Si no existe $rut en el arreglo
        if(!isset($arraySucursales[$rut])) {
            // Se crea como un arreglo para asignar las sucursales
            $arraySucursales[$rut] = [];
        }
        $drut = $raiz . "/" . $rut;
        $dirRut = opendir($drut);
        while ($sucursales = readdir($dirRut)) {
            if ($sucursales != "." && $sucursales != "..") {
                // No uses array_push(), es mejor agregar el elemento
                $arraySucursales[$rut][] = $sucursal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El resultado va a ser un arreglo asociativo donde cada *rut* contiene un arreglo de sucursales:

```
[
    'rut1' => ['sucursal1', 'sucursal2', 'sucursalX'],
    'rut2' => ['sucursal1'],
    'rutX' => ['sucursal1', 'sucursalX'],
];
```

Respecto a la recomendación de no usar `array_push()`, revisa [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php), que menciona:

> Nota: Si se utiliza array_push() para añadir un solo elemento al array, es mejor utilizar $array[] = ya que de esta forma no existe la sobrecarga de llamar a una función.

Para recorrer solo necesitas un ciclo por indice => valor:

```
foreach($arraySucursales as $rut => $sucursales) {
    // Ver el contenido de $rut, debería ser una cadena
    var_dump($rut);
    // Ver sucursales, debería ser un arreglo
    var_dump($sucursales);
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, nunca se me hubiese ocurrido eso, gracias Triby !!!

Comment: Oye, si quisiera añadirle los indices de todos modos, como haria para mantener la estructura ??

Comment: Los índices, como ya te había comentado, son las _rut_, para recorrer solo necesitas un ciclo `foreach($arraySucursales as $rut => $sucursales) { echo "$rut es el índice"; /* Arreglo de sucursales por rut: */ var_dump($sucursales); }`

Comment: Pero no logro obtener el valor del rut, hago un echo y no se obtiene el rut.

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes de `var_dump($arraySucursales);`? Agrega eso en la pregunta, por favor.

Comment: `array(3) { ["15835677-5"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } ["77187151-8"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["8935288-6"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" } }`

Comment: Se ve correcto. Por favor edita la pregunta para poner tu código actual y cómo tratas de recorrer el arreglo. En la respuesta agregué un ejemplo.